# How to manually map columns in Excel with different headers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[image: Excel example]

I want to write a function similar to simple Index-Match or Vlookup-Match.

Problem:
The values of the "Kadabra" columns should be shown in the "Jam" column and the "Shadabra" column in the "Jim" column. Given that the Columns will have consistent headers(Jim, Jam, Kadabra, Shadabra) but their positions may change(which means we cannot use column numbers).
"Abra" and "Jimmy" are the index values.

I'm looking for an excel formula solution. If there isn't one then a Visual Basic solution is also welcome.

Comment: Will Kadabra-Jam relation be hard coded in the formula or will you have a match table etc? And will you also be using the values of Abra & Jimmy (1, 2 & 3) in this matching?

Comment: Either hardcoded in the formula or I can create a match table. ( I hadn't thought about a match table yet.)
Yes. Abra:1 will Match with Jimmy:1 and will give other column values relatively.
Also, I'm relatively new to Excel. Apologies for not using the correct slang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use an Index Match Match formula as below, if you were to enter this formula into cell B8:

`=INDEX($A$1:$C$4,MATCH(A8,$A$1:$A$4,0),MATCH("Kadabra",$1:$1,0))`

And in C8:

`=INDEX($A$1:$C$4,MATCH(A8,$A$1:$A$4,0),MATCH("Shadabra",$1:$1,0))`

Then you could fill the formula down and it should bring the appropriate values into your Jimmy/Jim/Jam Table.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

First please check below screenshot:

[image]

I have created a match table at `E:F` in order to avoid nested `IF`s for that condition. You may move the match table to another sheet and change your formula accordingly.

Formula for `B8` is as below. You may drag-copy it down and right:

```
=VLOOKUP($A8,$A$2:$C$4,MATCH(VLOOKUP(B$7,$E:$F,2,0),$A$1:$C$1,0),0)
```